# How to retain search query after clicking search and printing result on same page using PHP

Tags: php, html

I have created my PHP page where I have search query field. After submitting query I am printing result on same page. The query is working fine but I want query to be displayed even after result displayed. i.e. query is being disappeared after result comes. How can I retain the query word/s along with result in webpage. This might be very basic and sounds like stupid but since I am newbie and tried so many ways but in vain.

Below is my code:

```
  <html>
  <head>
  <TITLE>PHP FORMS</TITLE>
    </head>
    <body algin=center>
    <p>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    <p>Enter Drug Name <input type="text" name="drugName"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="search"></p>
    </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Can anyone suggest valuable idea and cause for it?

Comment: *sidenote:* use lower case HTML tag names, quote attribute value with quotes, use CSS instead of `align` in element, and spell it right !

Comment: You didn't set the `value` of your text box. It won't show until you set it. Also, if you leave `action=""`, it is by default the same page.

Comment: use `method=get` instead of post to retain the value. It is the standard way.

Comment: By using `GET` method or by storing the value in `SESSION`

Comment: If you want to retain your POST method, you can use `$drugName=$_POST['drugName']; echo $drugName;` in your handler, if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<input type="text" name="drugName" 
 value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['drugName']) ? $_POST['drugName'] : '') ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your form method to GET and append as many strings as you want.  Then via PHP, use `$_GET['varstring']` value.

OR if you must use POST

```
foreach ($_POST as $set => $myval){
  echo "{$set} = {$myval}\n";
}
```